# Resuing a zip file from google colab

Tags: file, directory, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train a CNN on Google Colab. I have a files of 50,000 images. From googling around I found the best way to use them is to zip the files and then unzip them in the notebook. This has been pretty tedious because it takes a while to unzip the folder and every time I want run a new model I have to re unzip the folder and it takes a ton of time. Is there anyway to speed this up??

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
!unzip -uq "/zip folder on drive" -d "/new location folder"
```

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as accepted if it helped you resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering how to do this...

first, zip you file containing your images and upload to Google Drive

second, in Google Colab, mount your drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

third, copy the zip folder into your local environment

```
!cp "/file path with the zip image folder.zip" "whatever you want to      call the file when unzipped"
```

fourth, unzip in local colab into a folder you made

```
!unzip -uq "whatever you want to call the file when unzipped" -d "folder where you want them unzipped (or just make one up)"
```

You will have to do this every time, but it is super quick compared to what I was doing before

Answer (score 1):

Google colab is a temporary machine with temporary storage. You can only attach your drive or any other cloud storage to Colab and write scripts to automate the flow to run on every new notebook run.

I use Google cloud storage and I mount it in colab whenever i need to work on it.

This will be a bit faster than uploading and downloading through the GUI from the notepad.

The code to mount your google drive to colab is

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

This is  an example for copying

```
!cp -r /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/headTrainingDatastructure/eval /content/models/research/object_detection/
```

Comment: So after mounting drive to colab, you just copy the files from drive into the local colab you are using?

Comment: Could you explain more about what is happening in copying part of your code please?

Comment: You can move the zip from the Google drive to the colab's runtime storage. And then unzip there. This reduces time. I have given an example of a copy command that you can use.

Comment: What I don't understand is "/content/gdrive/My\ Drive/headTrainingDatastructure/eval /content/models/research/object_detection/

Comment: That's an example path. I used it to emphasize how to handle folders with spaces in them.